# How to add a column based on a comparison between an existing column and a list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I did:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(...
```

and in this `data` file (a dataframe), I have now a column `Country` listing all (or almost) the countries of the world.

Apart from this, I have a list named `eu` (by "list", I mean that `type(eu)==list` is `True`), listing all the European countries: `eu = ["Albania","Andorra",...]`

And now, I would like to run through the elements of the `Country` column of my `data` file and, each time I find a European country (an element in my list `eu`), insert the value "YES" in the corresponding row a new column, say `Europe`, firstly created in the dataframe `data`.

I browsed some posts containing the key-word `iterrows`, but I couldn't understand how it works in my case. I am starting with Python and there surely exists a simple solution, but I can't find it out.

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: I find this so difficult to follow. Please give a [mcve] because the description of the problem is confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np


data['IsEuropeanCountry'] = np.where(data['Country'].isin(eu), 'Yes', 'No')
```

---

For example,

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> eu = ['Greece', 'Germany']
>>> 
>>> data = pd.DataFrame(
...     [
...         [1, 'Greece'],
...         [2, 'Angola'],
...         [3, 'Germany'],
...         [4, 'USA']
...     ],
...     columns=['id', 'Country']
... )
>>> data
   id  Country
0   1   Greece
1   2   Angola
2   3  Germany
3   4      USA
>>> 
>>> data['IsEuropeanCountry'] = np.where(data['Country'].isin(eu), 'Yes', 'No')
>>> 
>>> data
   id  Country IsEuropeanCountry
0   1   Greece               Yes
1   2   Angola                No
2   3  Germany               Yes
3   4      USA                No
```

Comment: @Giorgios Excellent ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Define a method and then use it with apply  :

```py
def check_for_eu(row):
   country = row['country']
   if country in eu:
      row['europe']='yes'
   else:
      row['europe']='no'

   return row

df = df.apply(check_for_eu,axis=1)
```